# Div's height responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am writing to you with big problem,

if you make your browser window smaller, height does not change. Can someone help me fix it?

Here is fragment of html(with image background):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="slider" id="section1">
<div class="naglowek">
<h1>POLSKA - FRANCJA</h1>
<h2>NIEMCY - LUXEMBURG - BELGIA</h2>
<h3>Szybki i bezpieczny transport od drzwi do drzwi</h3>
<br />

<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-danger btn-lg" onclick="window.location.href='#section5'">ZAREZERWUJ</button>
</div>
</div>
...
```

And css fragment:

```
.slider{
    width:100%;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: 58px;
    background-image: url("img/baner2.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

I know, that now is bad with `height: 700px;`but i dont know how fix it.

I use bootstrap.

Comment: Go validate your code and fix all the errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ggoraj.pl%2F

Comment: use min-height or max-height for the 700px depending if you expect it to grown or shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, so you can use "vw" on the height, which will force the height of the container to listen to the width of the browser window (and slide everything up or down accordingly). That will make it very tall for wide browsers, but you can set a max-height of 700px.

So:

```
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vw;
    max-height: 700px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 58px;
    background-image: url(img/baner2.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
}

.naglowek {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Its work :)! but i have problem with text size. How can i make text responsive?

Comment: Well, you're doing it one way (using vw). That can work if it gives your desired effect. Otherwise, if you want more control, use media queries to adjust to specific sizes at certain browser widths.

Comment: Cool, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

use media query to fix it, so once the screen is smaller, you reduce the height of the div.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.slider{
width:100%;
height: 300px;
}
}
```

Means once the screen is smaller than 500px, the height will reduce